# Can I go out of the airport during a connecting intra-Schengen flight when I have a single-entry visa?

Tags: schengen, spain, tourist-visas

I have a return flight to India from Madrid, with a two-day layover in Amsterdam. I have got a single-entry visa. So when I leave Madrid, they will do the immigration checks and they might stamp on the passport that this tourist has departed from Schengen. However I need to get out of the airport in Amsterdam to travel. Can I do that with a single-entry visa?

Comment: Why do you think you will have exit immigration in Madrid before flying to Amsterdam?

Answer (score 26):

If you have a flight from Madrid to Amsterdam, there's no way you will get an exit stamp. This means you will still be in Schengen when arriving to Amsterdam, and can go out as you please. You will only leave Schengen when boarding for India.

Answer (score 12):

Exit checks will be done in Amsterdam. Your Madrid-Amsterdam flight will be a domestic flight and you will not pass through immigration. You don't need a transit visa for that flight.

Comment: Keep in mind, this means that your visa has to be valid through the date that you will depart from Amsterdam.

Comment: Your "No" is confusing. I guess it's directed at the claim that the passport might be stamped when leaving Madrid? It's easy to (mis?)interpret it as an answer to one of the two literal questions in the OP.

Comment: A flight from Madrid to Amsterdam is *not* domestic. Spain and the Netherlands are two different countries, even if they both are part of the Schengen zone and there are no immigration checkpoints when travelling between the countries.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo But it behaves exactly like a domestic flight.  As such, most people seem to be referring to an intra-Schengen flight as "domestic" - and so the language changes.

Comment: the language is confusing and should be avoided.

Comment: @MartinBonner No, it does *not* behave exactly like a domestic flight in situations where a distinction is relevant at all. Because it is an internation flight, e.g. the Montreal Convention applies and you are as a passenger subject to customs checks when arriving at your destination. Had it been a domestic flight, the Montreal Convention would not apply and you would not be subject to customs checks at the destination.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo For intra-EU travel that's much more theory than practice. Per international agreement travellers shouldn't *ordinarily* expect customs checks, ditto for Schengen and identity.

Comment: Customs checks have nothing to do with deciding whether a flight is domestic or not. I've had Customs checks in various cities in France, getting off a flight from CDG. Customs officers, at least in France (and I suppose it works at an Eu level), can check travellers wherever they want.